# Multiple necessary conditions vs intersection of conditions in Protege

Tags: ontology, protege

Is there any difference between the following ways of expressing multiple necessary conditions in ontology (via Protege)

1. Each necessary condition expressed one by one inside the SubclassOf Section (for class A):

   instrument some B

   object some C
2. All of those stated at once (via the class expression editor)

   instrument some B and object some C

Are 1 and 2 semantically the same?

Answer (score 1):

Yes they are equivalent. The choice of which way to go is yours: which approach do you find more readable? That is the best choice.